# Autowiring not working when used inside a java config bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

I am working on an existing webapp where most of the beans are defined and discovered using xml config. There are a bunch of xml files defined and included in the `contextConfigLocation` param of the web.xml, thus creating the web-application context.

For some new code that I am writing I decided to use java config.

```
@Configuration
public class UserChannelConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("deviceIOSDao")
    private DeviceIOSDao deviceIOSDao;

    @Bean
    public UserPayloadHandler defaultUserPayloadInstallationHandler() {
        return new DefaultUserPayloadInstallationHandler(deviceIOSDao);
    }
}
```

Since the webapp already uses xml based configuration I created a simple  xml config file(ios-user-channel-service-beans.xml) which defines the above config as a bean

```
<bean name="userChannelConfiguration" class="com.fiberlink.mdm.ios.user_channel.UserChannelConfiguration"/>
```

I included this in the web.xml along with the others as mentioned at the start

```
 <context-param>
        <description>locations of the Spring configuration files</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:com/somethingelse/ios-action-service-beans.xml, <!-- contains xml definition of my bean 'deviceIOSDao' -->
            classpath:com/something/ios-user-channel-service-beans.xml <!-- contains my java config bean -->
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Also my application-servlet.xml contains `<context:annotation-config />` which is supposed to enable some spring component to process my `@AutoWired` annotations and inject `deviceIOSDao` from the web-application context.

But `deviceIOSDao` is not getting autowired and i get a null pointer exception when I access the same at runtime in my code.

What am I missing?

Comment: you could import _ios-user-channel-service-beans.xml_ into _ios-action-service-beans.xml_  beacause this way you will have a unique context

Comment: Try declaring parameters for a bean factory method instead of autowiring the whole class.